# You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to transfer fund from my stripe test account to one of my connected account, but i am continuously getting insufficient error even i have balance in my stripe.

*{
"error": {
"code": "**balance_insufficient**",
"doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/balance-insufficient",
"message": "You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account. One likely reason you have insufficient funds is that your funds are automatically being paid out; try enabling manual payouts by going to [https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payouts."](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payouts.%22),
"type": "invalid_request_error"
}
}*

**Balance API result is:**

*{
"object": "**balance**",
"available": [
{
"amount": 1118069,
"currency": "usd",
"source_types": {
"card": 1118069
}
}
],
"livemode": false,
"pending": [
{
"amount": 89360,
"currency": "usd",
"source_types": {
"card": 89360
}
}
]
}*

Comment: Do you have automatic payouts enabled? Have you tried switching to manual like the error message suggests? With automatic payouts your balance won't be available for manual transfers.

Comment: How to make automatic payouts? and why that is essential to transfer fund to connected account?

Comment: You actually would need to disable automatic payouts (at the link in the error), otherwise the funds become part of an automatic payout as soon as they become available.

Comment: You need to have a sufficient available balance to create a transfer. Can you share the request you're making?

Comment: Thanks for help
I disable automatic payouts and its working fine now...